# How to prevent Bootstrap buttons from inheriting from each others class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a class container which holds a slideshow with a button. The button is located on the slideshow and changes its size with the responsiveness of the webpage . Right underneath a slideshow I want to center three more buttons. But no matter what I do the buttons keep inheriting the CSS from each other which results in my slideshow button being no longer responsive. When I shrink the screen the button keeps moving to the bottom of the screen overlapping my newly created three buttons. How can I fix this issue? How can I prevent my buttons from inheriting each others classes?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active"><span   style="color:#FFFFFF">Button Text</span></button>
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/sample1.jpg" alt="Sample Image" />
                <img src="images/sample2.jpg" alt="Sample Image"/>
                <img src="images/sample3.jpg" alt="Sample Image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="center-buttons">
        <div class="col-md-3 " style="min-height: 200px; background-color: red;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-security">Button Text</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 " style="min-height: 200px; background-color: yellow;">
            <button type="button" class=" btn btn-package">Button Text</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 " style="min-height: 200px; background-color: blue;">
            <button type="button" class=" btn btn-signup">Button Text</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .container{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding-right:0;
 padding-left:0;
 }
.btn{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:900;
 bottom:45%;
 right:25%;
 }
 .btn-default{
 background-color:#ED1C24 !important;
 border:none;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 }
 @media (max-width: 600px){
 .btn{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:900;
 bottom:45%;
 right:25%;
 }
 .btn-default{
 background-color:#ED1C24 !important;
 border:none;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 }
 }
 @media (max-width: 500px){
 .btn {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:900;
 bottom:45%;
 right:25%;
 }
 .btn-default{
 background-color:#ED1C24 !important;
 border:none;
 font-size:10px;
 text-align:center;
 }
 }
 .slider-wrapper.theme-default{
 max-height:500px;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
 .nivoSlider{
 position:relative;
 }
 .nivoSlider img{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 display:none;
 }
 .nivoSlider a{
 border:0;
 display:block;
 }
 .center-buttons{
 margin:0 auto 0;
 }
 .btn-security{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border-color:#1B75BB;
 color:#1B75BB;
 }
 .btn-package{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border-color:#1B75BB;
 color:#1B75BB;}
.btn-signup{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border-color:#F90B0B;
 color:#F90B0B;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by inheriting each other classes? For the overlap, add `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried given the button its own class name to add styles to instead of using the .btn classes?

```
<button type="button" class="my-button btn btn-default btn-lg active">Button</button>
```

And then call your css on my-button instead of btn.

```
.my-button{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:900;
    bottom:45%;
    right:25%;
}
```

Comment: No it did not work. my button on the slideshow still keep moving to the bottom of the screen and overlapping my new buttons when I shrink the screen to the mobile device size. However, if I completely delete my new buttons, it works just fine. And when I do inspect element .my-button{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:900;
    bottom:45%;
    right:25%;
} is crossed out in the browser

Comment: Bootstrap will automatically stack your items when you shrink the screen. You may be causing some of the problem by setting css to different size media screens instead of letting bootstrap do it for you. However first you could try wrapping the first button and the slideshow in a div so it knows it stays together. Also you should consider using the rows class along with the container and col class for positioning and not using css top left etc. There isn't really any use in using bootstrap if your going to tell the stuff where to be positioned using css.